# Definition of Cofibration and Fibration: Motivation, analogy and examples

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, motivation, fibration

I tried to understand the definitions of [cofibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofibration) and [fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration) through wikipedia. But I didn't get any motivation why such things are important, and through which basic natural question they come?

Also, I saw this first in the book of J. P. May, concise course in algebraic topology. The book explains many terminologies through maps between objects with lack of motivations (in my opinion). Therefore, I next moved to Wiki, but there also, no motivation for it.

I tried to understand them through some analogous definitions in category of module theory,  but I didn't succeed.

**Q. 1.**  What is motivation for defining the fibration and cofibration? What are simple examples of it?

**Q. 2** What are the analogous concepts of these two in category of modules or rings or something in algebra?

Comment: Fibration is a generalization of the path fibration and cofibration is the generalization of an inclusion of CW complexes.

Comment: More generally there's the mapping path space and the mapping cylinder respectively. They're in some sense the universal (and functorial) way of making a factorization of any morphism by a cofibration followed by a weak equivalence (a weak eq. followed by a fibration, resp.)

Comment: If you like modules you may look at the model structure in the category of chain complexes https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+chain+complexes

Comment: Also, note that there isn't a notion of fibrations or cofibrations in a plain ordinary *category* -- these notions are part of *extra structure* that we can equip a category with (a "model category"). The structure we usually add to **Top** is related to the notion of homotopy equivalence. The structures we usually add to categories of chain complexes are related to the notion of quasi-isomorphism.

Comment: There is quite a lot of motivation in Chapter 7 of the book Topology and Groupoids: (http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) The condition allows a proof of  for example a gluing theorem for homotopy equivalences.  That book also gives uses of fibrations of groupoids,

Comment: Brown: your book is interesting. Thanks for informing about it and motivation.

Comment: I cannot withhold myself from echoing your last comment. The book mentioned (and written) by @RonnieBrown is a very nice book.